# Maximizing the value of a two variable function along any curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, maxima-minima, infinitesimals

I read that, of all the points on an origin-centered circle in the x-y plane, the function $z=ax+by$ is maximum (or minimum) at the point where $\frac{x}{y}=\frac{a}{b}$

I think this is too specific. I thought of maximizing any function $z(x,y)$ along any (well behaved: continuous, differentiable, etc) curve $y=f(x)$.

What I thought of is:

Suppose we're currently at a point $(x_1,f(x_1))$. Now, what direction we'd have to take to get to this point's nearest neighbour point along the curve $y=f(x_1)$? Suppose we change $x_1$ by an infinitesimally small amount $dx$. Then change in $y$ would be $f'(x_1)dx$.

So, we'd have to change by the vector $dx \hat{i}+ f'(x_1)dx \hat{j}$ to go to a neighbouring point along the curve.

The change in $z(x,y)$ as we move from $(x_1, f(x_1))$ to this neighbour point on the curve is given by its gradient dotted with the change vector ($dx \hat{i}+ f'(x_1)dx \hat{j}$)

So, change in $z$ is:

$$\left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \hat{i} + \frac{\partial z}{ \partial y} \hat{j}\right)\cdot \left(dx \hat{i}+ f'(x_1)dx \hat{j}\right) $$

$$=\frac{ \partial z}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} f'(x_1)dx$$

If the function is maximum (or minimum) at $(x_1, f(x_1))$, then this change should be 0.

So, $$\frac{ \partial z}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} f'(x_1)dx=0$$

which gives

$$\frac{ \partial z}{\partial x}  + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} f'(x_1)=0$$

Have I got this condition right? The condition for the function to be maximum (or minimum) along the curve? In the special case that $y=f(x)$ is a circle and $z=ax+by$, my equation gives us the familiar condition $\frac{x_1}{f(x_1)}=\frac{a}{b}$.

Comment: These types of problems are best handled using Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: @OliverJones I googled it. It seems to be above my high-school math level. I'll try to understand it later. Is my method any good?

Comment: You say that Lagrange multipliers is too advanced for you but you use terms like gradient and partial derivatives. I advise you to leave this until you've learned multivariable calculus.

Comment: I should point out that a circle can't be written in the form $y=f(x)$.

Comment: @OliverJones Langrange multipliers hasn't been in my syllabus, gradients and partial derivatives have been. I'll try to understand Langrange multipliers. I'm just asking if my method is right.

Comment: If you've covered partial derivatives and gradients then you should be able to understand the method of Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: @OliverJones I'll try and understand Langrange multipliers. But what part of my reasoning is incorrect? Is my post confusing/not clear?

Comment: Your equation seems correct for this reason. You can substitute your constraint equation $y=f(x)$ into $z(x,y)$ to get a function of one variable $z(x,f(x))$. Differentiating this with respect to $x$ using the chain rule gives your equation.

Comment: @OliverJones Oh thanks. I think  I just over-complicated it.

Comment: There are some steps in your argument that need justification. For example, if you're at a max or min, why should the dot product be zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your equation for the infinitesimal change in $z$ is essentially a [differential](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/Differentials.aspx) taken for infinitesimal change in the direction $\langle 1, f'(x_1) \rangle$. And when you divide out the $dx$, the equation becomes something like a [directional derivative](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/DirectionalDeriv.aspx) of $z(x, y)$, only the "direction" $\langle 1, f'(x_1) \rangle$ may not be a unit vector. The magnitude of the direction does not matter though, if we are only considering points where the derivative is 0.

This sounds right to me. If a point were a maximum or minimum, the directional derivative cannot be nonzero, because that would imply the function increases immediately in some direction. So it must be 0 at the candidate extrema. Keep in mind that just because the derivative is 0 doesn't guarantee an actual minimum or maximum point; it could also be a saddle/inflection point.

As a side note, the original problem you're considering, maximizing/minimizing a function of two variables given a constraint that $y = f(x)$, sounds awfully like a Lagrange multipliers question, with the constraint being $0 = g(x, y) = f(x) - y$. That is another, more mainstream way of approaching the problem.